# Codeigniter $this->db->affected_rows() always returns 1

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter version 2.0.3. I'm trying get the number of affected rows after an update query using

```
$this->db->affected_rows
```

It always returns 1 even if no row had been updated. I tried with

```
mysql_affected_rows()
```

and it returns -1 for a query failure and 0 if no record had been updated .

Edit included my code

I'm just using

```
$country_id = $this->input->post('country_id');
$time=$this->input->post('time');

$insert_array = array(
  'country' => $this->input->post('name')
);
$this->db->update('country_master', $insert_array, array("country_id" => $country_id,"last_updated"=>$time));
$afftectedRows=$this->db->affected_rows();
```

Comment: Would you mind showing your code?

Comment: that depends on the query you are using before 

    $this->db->affected_rows

if you can show your code it will be easy to share the solution.

Comment: H'mmm it was an error from my part.Its working fine now

Answer (score 26):

Actually my code was like this

```
if (!$country_id) {
    $this->db->insert('country_master', $insert_array);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    $this->db->update('country_master', $insert_array, array("country_id" => $country_id, "last_updated" => $time));
}
$afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
```

And i modified it to

```
if (!$country_id) {                
    $this->db->insert('country_master', $insert_array);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    $this->db->update('country_master', $insert_array, array("country_id" => $country_id, "last_updated" => $time));
    $afftectedRows = $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

And its working fine now.

And thank you very much for the replies..

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.
Any technique to get the affected row while multiple rows insert?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have moved 1 character down 1 line to fix the issue.  Your question seems like a perfect candidate for closure as **Off-topic: Typo**.